# Aspire 4738zg no driver support for Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, acer-aspire

What do I do if there are no available drivers for Windows XP. I really need to be using XP since my project doesn't work on Windows 7. And I don't want to resort to virtualization (XP Mode, Virtual Box).I got to the acer site and here's what I got:
[image]

I tried all the drivers for wi-fi that are on the resource dvd that came with the laptop but they were all incompatible with Windows XP. What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to know the WiFi brand + chipset  and then look for another Acer laptop with the same hw with XP Driver.

There is nothing else you can do, unless you code the drivers yourself...